# Best Practice to store link in string

Tags: android, string

I have two options how use the link for the application when I need to open the link in just simple browser.

Rather I save it in the `strings.xml` file as

```
<string name="link_openBrowser_calendar" translatable="false">/schedule/</string>
```

that looks quite ugly lets say or just to save it in the Constants.java file as

```
final static final String linkSchedule = "/schedule/";
```

In some cases I have a lot of such links, that require additional parameter

```
<string name="link_openBrowser_account_byId" translatable="false"> 
    /accounts/account/?id=%1$s 
</string>
```

or even more parameters

```
<string name="view_meeting_time_inOneDay_period">%1$s at \n%2$s – %3$s</string>
```

that is useful when part of the string need to be translated, but in the code it looks quite massive and hardly to read.

```
String time = mEvent.isAllDay() ? getString(R.string.view_meeting_time_inOneDay_allDay, isTodayStr)
                : getString(R.string.view_meeting_time_inOneDay_period, isTodayStr, startStr, finishStr);
```

Which one of these methods is more productive in the ways of scalability, performance or just clearness? I believe at some point it matters where to store this links, while they are not used all the time and only need "on the go", rather I spend memory on storing them as `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that it is much better to store the resource strings that represent links to API or server links in the `.gradle` file. The idea here is that during the development stage we want to test our API or whatever with **debug/dev** API links, so with setting it in the `.gradle` file we can create different strings for each build type.

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    release {
      buildConfigField("String", "API_URL", "\"https://api.release\"")

      // These values are defined only for the release build, which
      // is typically used for full builds and continuous builds.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${minutesSinceEpoch}\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "${minutesSinceEpoch}")
      ...
    }
    debug {
      buildConfigField("String", "API_URL", "\"https://api.debug\"")

      // Use static values for incremental builds to ensure that
      // resource files and BuildConfig aren't rebuilt with each run.
      // If they were dynamic, they would prevent certain benefits of
      // Instant Run as well as Gradle UP-TO-DATE checks.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"0\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "0")
    }
  }
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

If you need text strings for your application with optional text styling and formatting, `strings.xml` is convenient. For instance, you can use it to translate your strings into other languages. Android takes a look at user preferences and selects the `strings.xml` file from the correct localization folder (`values` is the base one, `values-xx` stands for other languages). On the other hand, you should use a separate class (e.g., `Constants.java`) for other strings which you need to use in the global scope. Defining that kind of constant strings in `Constants.java` is the best practice.